# inference engine based chatbot in java

Tags: java, prolog, chatbot

I want to build a chatbot which can parse through given knowledge to add facts to its knowledge base and use these facts and an inference engine to answer questions. What existing solutions can I use to build this? If there are no ready made solutions for something like this are there any frameworks I can put together to achieve this. I would prefer java but any other languages would also be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out various rule/inference engines at http://java-source.net/open-source/rule-engines , you can couple any of these and deploy them in Google App Engine and enabler XMPP. The XMPP will give you the chat interface quite quickly with Google App Engine, and you can focus on actual inference engine. Ask more if u need help!

Answer (score 1):

For Prolog systems, please refer to [Prolog's info-page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/prolog/info) for current implementations.